# Comparing mortality rates between two treatment groups

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, biostatistics, propensity-scores

Would appreciate some insight on this. My aim is to compare mortality rates between two treatment groups (treatment A vs treatment B) for a given acute disease. The data goes back some 8 years (retrospective). What would be the right statistical test for this and would propensity score matching be desirable? Thanks in advance.
Edit: It will be comparing short term (7 day and 30 day mortality). I'll also be collecting data on several other variables such as age, gender, race, weight, comorbid conditions.

Comment: If A has 603 fatalities among 1000 subjects and B has 715 among 1300 ,then R code `prop.test(c(603, 715), c(1000,1300), cor=F)$p.val` returns $0.01085274 < 0.02$ so proportion $0.603$ for A is significantly greater than  $0.550$ for B at the 2% level. // However, additional relevant information from propensity scores might show significant differences from much closer proportions. // Maybe giving more details in your Q would get you a more useful A.

Comment: Thanks Bruce! Helpful. I know sample size (how many years back to go in my case- given retrospective study) calculation should be done a-priori but can I please ask how these are done for retrospective studies, power 80%. There are simple calculators for prospective studies and RCTs but I think it's more complex with retrospective data. My outcome variable, i.e. mortality is only around 3% for the acute disease I'm studying. So how do I work out the sample size that will be required to detect statistically significant differences in mortality between the two treatment groups? Many thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to provide more details on your study and the data you will have available. It's hard to provide a helpful answer otherwise.

Comment: An issue with retrospective studies may be how much the effectiveness of the ;treatment' may have changed over time. Changes may be in the treatment itself or in environmental/infrastructural  factors affecting subjects. (Pollution, general availability of healthcare, gender/racial diversity of subject pool, etc.)

Comment: The mortality is being measured is inhospital mortality therefore it's the short term effect of acute treatment for an acute disease. My sample size calculations assuming 3% and 2.5% deaths in each group, with alpha 0.05 and power .8 came out to 33K!! Surely a smaller number has to suffice! (I hope).